# Swift : [MyApp.MyClass retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting the following crash from my App.

> `[MyApp.MyClass retain]`

I do not know what to do about this issue at all to  be honest with you.

This is only occuring in my swift class. I need to know why is is occurring and what is the general way to fix this.

Here is my swift code in general (There is more to it, but I probably don't need to post it all.

```
class MyClass  : NSObject, ApiDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate  {

var apiClient : Api?


func initMyClass (authKey : NSString?) {

    apiClient = Api(authKey: authKey, debugMode:false)
    apiClient?.delegate = self

}
```

Comment: We obviously don't want to see all of your code, but you need to construct the smallest possible example that reproduces this behavior (a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). The code here is not enough.

Comment: As an aside, the method name, `initMyClass` is curious. Is your intent for that to be a proper `init` method (in which case you should replace `initMyClass` with just `init`)? You do not mean it as an `init` method, I would not start the name with `init`.

Comment: @Rob, ok I will change that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Rob said, it looks like the culprit is methods that begin with `init` but are not initializers. It seems like Swift does something strange with these method around memory management.

Anyway, in my own code, I renamed all of these methods to begin with `setup` instead of `init`, and I haven't received the "retain message sent to deallocated instance" error again.

Xcode should really provide a warning to help prevent this error.